# What is the purpose of set_order in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add a new attribute set and I have this data:

```
$data = [
   'attribute_set_name' => 'Sample attribute set',
   'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
   'sort_order' => 200,
];
```

Could someone explain what the `sort_order` means here? I just started to learn Magento 2, so it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this `sort_order` is a field where you put a number in order to sort the object or xml fields.

You can define ascendent or descendent but most of the places I've seen are ascendent.

EDITED:

These are 4 fields that we created with the layout. Have a look at the code and see one of the parameters is *sort_order*.

[image]

```
 <group id="customer">

            <field id="permission_info" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="100"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Allow edit customer data</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>

            <field id="permission_freetext" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="110"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Show free text field</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>

            <field id="permission_payment" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="120"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Allow edit condition and payment method</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>

            <field id="permission_bank" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="130"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Allow edit bank data and payment days</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>              

        </group>
```

If I change the values of the field with the *id="permission_bank"* and I put in the *sort_order* parameter a value between 101 and 109, this field will go between **Allow edit customer data** and **Show free text field**:

[image]

It's just a tool to sort.

Comment: I still didn't quite get it...

Comment: Have a look again, I edited a bit. :D

Answer (score 0):

`sort_order` is added to tell the system where you want to display the field in the form.
Higher the `sort_order` lower it will be displayed in the form.